# Replace scene causing memory leak and app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a cocos2d project which is a game with many scenes. 
When I call replace scene ,I use

```
    [scene2 removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
```

In the dealloc method.
Also, I have removed all the unused spritesheets by using

```
    NSString *PngName = [atlas.AtlasName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    NSString *PlistName = [atlas.AtlasName stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:PlistName];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrameByName:PngName];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
```

When I check the description of my

```
    [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
```

by using

```
     NSLog(@"%@",[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]description]);
```

, It shows me that it removes the unused spritesheets and sprites
 but it does not free the memory when I check on device with Instrumets. This results in app crash. I also removed touch delegate on each scene. I have taken care of every variable with 'retain' property to be released in dealloc. 
I tried to use ARC also to solve this issue but still it is not freeing the memory...
It just goes on adding memory allocations with each next scene loaded and finally crashes.
Can anybody please help me to solve this issue??

Comment: do you use cocosBuilder? it's just a quick guess

Comment: check the sprite you are using is releasing somewhere

Comment: impossible to diagnose without more details and code. Try using Instruments, also post the crash log, call stack and code where crash occurs ( if it's in main add exception breakpoint)

Comment: It is the issues that my app goes on eating memory even after i release the sprites

Comment: Have you tried running the static analyzer in XCode this often reveals a bunch of issues.  It may also show you the cause of your memory leak.

Comment: Thanks @RobSegal I used static Analyzer it removed most of the memory leaks but sill it shows that it's eating memory. also many analyzer points are pointing to cocos2d inbuilt classes too. should I interfere with the inbuilt classes of cocos2d to resolve this memory leak?

Comment: Yes sadly static analyzer only shows you potential memory leaks.  It's up to you to decide if they are actually leaks or not.  Probably issues in Cocos2D are not worth pursuing.  The suggestions from @LearnCocos2D would help.  You can also add an "all exceptions" breakpoint in your breakpoint list.  Would be interesting to see the call stack at the point of the crash.